# themeweb.aspx error

Tags: error, theme

I installed a few new themes a few weeks ago and everything went off without a hitch. Yesterday, I go to my site and attempt to change the theme and get this error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or
>   more rows contain values violating
>   non-null, unique, or foreign-key
>   constraints.

Any ideas what would cause this? I only get it on the themeweb.aspx page. The only recent changes I made was installing those new themes…

I'm on WSS 2007.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look in the file

```
 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\SPTHEMES.XML
```

for any duplicate template ids and remove the dups.